Suggestion on how to get the trees removed infront of garage door

You see the picture? I want to remove that tree. Its in front of the garage door. It was planted long ago. Probably 15 years. I wanted to ideally remove it from there completely.
Can it be done safely without affecting foundation like the drive way and the building's foundation itself?
If not I would like to cut it to the ground level leaving the stump.

I agree, I wouldn't pull any roots that are actually in the driveway or walkway substrate.  You won't be able to pack gravel back in from the side well enough.
You can cut the tree off at the ground. Mulching over the stump would help prevent regrowth (which you would just trim away), and applying a nitrogen fertilizer like potassium nitrate would accelerate its decomposition quite a bit.
What I usually do is a compromise between cutting at grade and actually pulling the whole thing.  I dig the tree out as far as is convenient, cut the roots at that point, and leave whatever was inconvenient in the ground. Mulch and fertilizer help things the same way as if it was cut at grade.

Perhaps not for this situation, but I also sometimes cut the stumps above grade because I think they are beautiful as they decompose.  Fertilizer again accelerates the show.
